# Rethrowing SomeException

Tags: exception, haskell

The function `forkFinally` requires you to write a handler against `SomeException`. What I need is a way to rethrow the unhandled exceptions. Here's a sample code, which fails to compile because on the last line the `e` is ambiguous:

```
finallyHandler :: Either SomeException () -> IO ()
finallyHandler z = case z of
  Right () -> cleanUp
  Left someE | Just ThreadKilled <- fromException someE -> cleanUp
             | Just e <- fromException someE -> cleanUp >> throwIO e
```

Of course the first thing coming to mind is to simply throw the `someE` instead, i.e.:

```
             ...
             | otherwise -> cleanUp >> throwIO someE
```

And indeed it will compile, but then it will result in wrapping of all of incoming exceptions in `SomeException` when they pass this handler. This just can't be right. And what if I have multiple such handlers down the stack - I'll get a trash like `SomeException $ SomeException $ RealException`.

Am I missing something? What's the proper way of handling this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing unexpected behavior?   If you haven't actually triggered something undersirable then I think you are worrying over nothing.  A quick test indicates that the "right thing" is already being done.  That is, if you catch then throw a `SomeException` you can still catch the original exception.  Here's an example using `ErrorCall` as the underlying exception:

```
> catch (catch (throw (SomeException (ErrorCall "hi")))
               (\(e::SomeException) -> throw e)) 
        (\(ErrorCall e) -> putStrLn e)
hi
```

This is because the definition of `throw` uses `toException` and `toException` is identity for `SomeException`:

```
instance Exception SomeException where
    toException se = se
    fromException = Just
```

Comment: Yeah. Just figured that out after looking thru source. Also, turns out that the [implementation of `throwIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-IO.html#throwIO) wraps all incoming exceptions in `SomeException` anyway: `throwIO e = IO (raiseIO# (toException e))`.